# Better/faster way to concatenate two columns after removing duplicate values in one?

Tags: r, string, performance

I have a dataframe with two columns, the last one with duplicates:

```
 #reproducible data
    my.df <- data.frame(nr = paste(1:6,1,sep="_"),
                        text = c("aa","bb","aa",NA,"bb","xxxx"))
   nr text
1 1_1   aa
2 2_1   bb
3 3_1   aa
4 4_1 <NA>
5 5_1   bb
6 6_1 xxxx
```

I want to group the values in the first column and after that adding the value of the second column. I have found a way to do this by:

```
apply(aggregate(nr~text, my.df, FUN=function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "/"))[,c(2,1)],1,FUN=function(x) paste(x[1],x[2], sep = ": "))
```

Which gives:

```
"1_1/3_1: aa" "2_1/5_1: bb" "6_1: xxxx"
```

This is the result I wanted, but the code seems rather long. I have a feeling there must be a better, perhaps also faster way to do this?

Oh yeah, NA's should be removed from the result.

## EDIT:

Thanks for all the answers. I thought there would be a far easier solution than my own, but apparently there isn't. Readability is (IMHO) very subjective, so I did a benchmark:

```
microbenchmark(RHA(my.df),Heroka_DT(my.df),Heroka_Base(my.df),Jubbles(my.df),times=100L)

Unit: milliseconds
               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
         RHA(my.df)  9.116587  9.315988  9.662611  9.572361 10.036792
   Heroka_DT(my.df) 12.148374 12.448035 13.009290 12.766685 13.475480
 Heroka_Base(my.df)  2.947448  6.910890  7.475239  7.172847  7.614657
     Jubbles(my.df) 16.615067 40.609642 42.265267 41.799625 43.056632
      max neval
 10.78943   100
 21.12477   100
 15.97665   100
 61.68414   100
```

Base solutions clearly are faster than others in this case. As Heroka has both the shortest and the fastest solution, I will accept his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use data.table, it's a bit shorter and (IMHO) more readable:

```
library(data.table)

res <- setDT(my.df)[!is.na(text),.(output=sprintf("%s: %s",paste(nr,collapse="/"),text)),text][,output]
res

> res
[1] "1_1/3_1: aa" "2_1/5_1: bb" "6_1: xxxx"
```

We can do something very similar in base-R:

```
sapply(split(my.df, my.df$text),function(x){with(x, sprintf("%s: %s",paste(nr, collapse="/"),text[1]))})

           aa            bb          xxxx 
"1_1/3_1: aa" "2_1/5_1: bb"   "6_1: xxxx"
```

Comment: `by` = `sapply` + `split`, so you could do `by(my.df, my.df$text,function(x)...`

Answer (score 2):

More readable (IMO) than `data.table` but not shorter :)

```
# dplyr_0.4.3
library(dplyr)

(my.df %>%
filter(!(is.na(text))) %>%
group_by(text) %>%
summarize(my.nrs = paste(nr, collapse = "/")) %>%
ungroup() %>%
mutate(res = paste(my.nrs, text, sep = ": ")))$res
```

Answer (score 2):

I like Jubbles `dplyr` approach, however, I think that it can be made even more readable by using the very helpful `dplyr::do()` function.

```
my.df %>%
  group_by(text) %>%
  do(new_nr = paste(.$nr, collapse = "/")) %>%
  do(done = paste(.$new_nr, .$text, sep = ": "))
```

One note on the `dplyr::do()` function.  When it is not part of a chain of pipes, it takes two arguments, data and a function, i.e. `do(.data, .fun)`.  However, when you pipe, the data automatically is placed in the first arguments as usual.  Unlike the other `dplyr` functions, however, you must refer to the data you have passed to `do()`.  You do this by using the `$` as usual, however inside of the data's name you will refer to the data you passed to `do` as `.`, hence `.$`.  Said another way, `do()` does not adopt the non-standard evaluation approach that the other `dplyr` functions adopt. This is of course done on purpose as it increase the functionality of the `do()` function.  For example, it allows you to call `lm`.

Comment: You code gives an error: `Error in do_.tbl_dt(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default`

Comment: @RHA, Hmmm...  It works fine for me.  Did you load the `dplyr` library?  I believe the error message says that the `do` function is missing a function to evaluate the data with.  However, looking at the code this clearly is not the case.  Each call to `do` contains a call to `paste`.  To debug it is sometimes convenient to abandon the chain of pipes.  For example `d <- group_by(my.df, text) ; d <- do(d, new_nr = paste(d$nr, collapse = "/"))` etc....  Let me know what you find out.